# Data Binding Not Working When Implemented As MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

So I wanted to build a reverse timer with MVVM. Here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="GcMain" x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Example.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="App" Height="560" Width="800" Background="#841212" Closing="Window_Closing" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="Vm"/>
    </Window.Resources>
...
 <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                            <TextBlock  DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Vm}" Text="{Binding TimeLefter, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="12" FontStyle="Oblique"/>
                            <TextBox  DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Vm}" Text="{Binding TimeLefter, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="12" FontStyle="Oblique"/>
...
```

And here is the ViewModel:

```
namespace Example.ViewModel
{
    class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string _timeLeft;
        DispatcherTimer _timer;
        static TimeSpan _time;

        private string timeLeft;

        public string TimeLefter
        {
            get
            {
                return timeLeft;
            }
            set
            {
                timeLeft = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            _time = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(45);
        }

        public void StartTimer()
        {
            _timer = new DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), DispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate
            {
                MessageBox.Show(TimeLefter); // this shows correct!
                TimeLefter = _time.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
                if (_time == TimeSpan.Zero)
                {
                    _timer.Stop();
                }
                _time = _time.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1));
            }, Application.Current.Dispatcher);
            _timer.Start();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Code in MainWindows.xaml.cs:

```
...
InitializeComponent();
MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
mainWindowViewModel.StartTimer();
...
```

While the messagebox show perfectly correct output the binding doesn't work!

Comment: You've got two instances of the view model class, one in Window.Resources, one created in code behind. Remove the resource and set `DataContext = mainWindowViewModel;` in the MainWindow constructor.

Comment: You should also not assume that a DispatcherTimer (or any other timer) runs precisely. So instead of subtracting one second from a TimeSpan on each tick, better calculate an end time in advance, and subtract `DataTime.Now` from that end time to get the remaining TimeSpan.

Comment: @I had no idea on you comment on `DispatcherTimer`. Will do!